# How to convert dd-mmm-yy hh.mm nvarchar to any date format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very specific format for date and time stored in my table as nvarchar.
The format is 'DD-MMM-YY hh.mm' ex. '30-NOV-20 19.25' , '22-JAN-52 13.34' etc.
Is there any way to convert the above nvarchar to standard datetime formats within particular table?

Comment: can you show, what you tried?

Comment: try_convert() would be a good start.  just have to replace the period with a colon.  Select try_convert(datetime,replace('30-NOV-20 19.25','.',':'))

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Convert(DateTime, Replace(YourDateColumn, '.', ':'))
From   YourTable
```

Your format would be fine if you had a colon between the hours and minutes.  Use the replace function to accomodate that.

When you select a datetime value in SQL Server Management Studio, you should understand that it is determining how to display the value. If you want it to display in another way, you need to convert it back to a string while applying a format.  For example:

```
Select PERSON_BDAY, 
       Convert(VarChar(10), Convert(DateTime, Left(PERSON_BDAY, 9)), 1) 
From   YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeMastros, the only problem here is that years from range 00-49 converted to 2000-2049 and years from 50-99 to 1950-1999 respectively

Comment: Tried something like 
Select Convert(DateTime, Replace(BIRTH_DATE, '.', ':'), 6) to eliminate century
But the format remains the same yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm

Comment: SQL server has a "Two Digit Year Cutoff" configuration value that defaults to 2049. Meaning... if a 2 digit year is less than or equal to 49, the year is interpreted as 20 + year, otherwise 19 + year. This is a server setting. In SQL Server Management Studio, right click the server node, click properties, click "Advanced" in "Select a page".

Comment: With the 2 examples in your original post, what is your expected result?